# Aws Cognito: Secret hash with Java SDK (not Android) and ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

i try to register a user in my amazon cognito user pool with username and password from my java backend but i always get the error:

```
Unable to verify secret hash for client
```

in the documentation i don't found any information how to pass the clientSecret in the register request and i don't like to create an (backend) app without a clientSecret.

My code looks like this

```
identityProvider = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).build();

Map<String, String> authParameters = new HashMap<>();
authParameters.put("USERNAME", "username");
authParameters.put("PASSWORD", "password");
authParameters.put("SECRET_HASH", "secret copy and paste from the aws console"); // i read in a forum post, that this should work

AdminInitiateAuthRequest authRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest();
authRequest.withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH);
authRequest.setAuthParameters(authParameters);
authRequest.setClientId("clientId");
authRequest.setUserPoolId("userPoolId");

AdminInitiateAuthResult authResponse = identityProvider.adminInitiateAuth(authRequest);
```

Thanks
Marcel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To register users you should use the [SignUp API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SignUp.html). The secret hash can be calculated as follows in Java:

```
public String calculateSecretHash(String userPoolclientId, String userPoolclientSecret, String userName) {
        if (userPoolclientSecret == null) {
            return null;
        }

        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(
                userPoolclientSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
                HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
        try {
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256_ALGORITHM);
            mac.init(signingKey);
            mac.update(userName.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(userPoolclientId.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            return Encoding.encodeBase64(rawHmac);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while calculating ");
        }
    }
```

Can you please elaborate your use case of creating users from your backend instead of directly calling Amazon Cognito from your clients?

Edit: We have updated our documentation to include a section about how to [compute the secret hash](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html#cognito-user-pools-computing-secret-hash).

Comment: I'll provide an API and the clients/customer should not see that cognito is used. Maybe later, i'll change to an own "User Management" or different Provider. The API should not be changed for our customers.

Comment: Makes sense. By the way, we would love to hear what features we can deliver so that you don't have to change to your own user management :)..

Comment: To be honest: a better documentation and examples about the concept of cognito user pools and federation is a good starting point. The linking between accounts is not well documented. a small case from my side. a user logged in via facebook - a federated identity will be created. after that, i need to check if this user in my user pool (before, i need to figure out the email from facebook by myself). if not, i need to create this user and need to link this pool user account to the federated account. i managed that, but it was a long way to found the correct flow.

Comment: An other question is. The customer is using facebook for login. In federated identities the account is linked to a cognito user pool. How can i fetch the linked user pool data - just with the accessToken of facebook ?

Comment: If you've some time, you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42139567/is-this-auth-flow-possible-with-amazon-cognito-identity-and-user-pool. i described my flow a little bit more

Comment: Thanks a lot for the feedback. We are continuously trying to take feedback from our customers and improve upon those (we updated our docs with the computation of the secret hash).
We have heard similar requests for federation and user pool integration and will take that as a feature request for our roadmap.

Comment: I have a feedback that might interest you. My reason to create user using backend is that I need request on all my user. For example: get all of my users with the same company. Cognito doesn't support that kind of requests even if my user have an attribute "company". So I have a table "user" with no password but users metadata. I create my users with the backend to keep cognito and the table in sync.

Answer (score -1):

The following code works perfectly:

```
    AdminInitiateAuthRequest adminInitiateAuthRequest = new AdminInitiateAuthRequest().withAuthFlow(AuthFlowType.ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH).withClientId("<ID of your client application>").withUserPoolId("<your user pool ID>")
            .addAuthParametersEntry("USERNAME", "<your user>").addAuthParametersEntry("PASSWORD", "<your password for the user>");
    AdminInitiateAuthResult adminInitiateAuth = identityProvider.adminInitiateAuth(adminInitiateAuthRequest);
    System.out.println(adminInitiateAuth.getAuthenticationResult().getIdToken());
```

Comment: what is identityProvider? its just there but i dont know where this come from

Comment: ah AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).build();

Comment: Where are you setting the secret hash?  My guess is that your App Client was setup without the client secret.